# Как убрать остановку программы при использовании метода _gethce из библиотеки conio.h

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Моя задача сделать так что бы экран обновлялся постоянно, но когда я добавил функцию _gethce что бы отслеживать нажатия, обновление стало происходить только при самом нажатии, как сделать обновление независимым от нажатий?

```
void Move(Player &pl) 
{
    switch (_getche())
    {
        case 'a':
            pl.point_y=pl.point_y-1;
            pl.ChangePositiont('$');
            break;
        case 'd':
            pl.point_y = pl.point_y + 1;
            pl.ChangePositiont('$');
            break;
        case 's':
            pl.point_x = pl.point_x + 1;
            pl.ChangePositiont('$');
            break;
        case 'w':
            pl.point_x = pl.point_x - pl.jumpforce;
            pl.ChangePositiont('$');
            break;
    }
    pl.Gravity();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В `conio.h` есть еще одна замечательная :) функция — `_kbhit();`, просто сообщающая, была ли нажата клавиша или нет.

Вот и проверяйте, и вызывайте `_getch()` только тогда, когда надо.

Comment: не помоголо 

if (_kbhit)
    {
        switch (_getche())
        {
        case 'a':
            pl.point_y = pl.point_y - 1;
            pl.ChangePositiont('$');
            break;
        case 'd':
            pl.point_y = pl.point_y + 1;
            pl.ChangePositiont('$');
            break;
        case 's':
            pl.point_x = pl.point_x + 1;
            pl.ChangePositiont('$');
            break;
        case 'w':
            pl.point_x = pl.point_x - pl.jumpforce;
            pl.ChangePositiont('$');
            break;
        }
    }

Comment: [Восхищенно] Вы что, и в самом деле так и написали —  `if (_kbhit)` ? Без вызова функции, только ее адрес?

Comment: Я вызываю этот If внутри функции которую я вызываю True While циклом

Comment: while (1) 
    {
        cout << "Здоровье: " << player.HP << endl;
        ShowScene();
        Move(player);
        system("cls");
    }
функция Move

Comment: Еще раз и медленно, как для милиционера — вы написали `if (_kbhit)`  вместо `if (_kbhit())`? И не грузите меня кусками вашей программы, не имеющими никакого отношения к вопросу...

Comment: Спасибо большое ,вы абсолютно правы!